# WCF disable chunked Transfer-Encoding

Tags: c#, wcf, http, stream, web-config

I use a restful WCF, and i call a method which has got a stream return type and this is the Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 11:25:29 GMT

6
1;1;

0
```

I would like to **disable** the

> Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Because it write some plus information what i don't need (6 and 0 in the body)

How can i do it?

Comment: I'd recommend to just write the client so that it properly handles T-E: chunked.

Comment: Agreed.  Per [RFC 7230](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-4.1), "A recipient MUST be able to parse and decode the chunked transfer coding."  Better to fix the client than to make your service cater to broken implementations, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a WCF endpoint you need to specify what transfer mode ([`TransferMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode(v=vs.110).aspx)) you are using.

- If it is set to `StreamedResponse`, `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` will be added automatically to the response headers, `Content-Length` will be automatically omitted and there is nothing you can do about that, even if you set the `Content-Length` explicitly. It is EITHER Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding, they replace each other depending on transfer mode, read [this (the first paragraph)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).
- If it is set to `Buffered`, `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` will be not be added automatically, which will allow `Content-Length` to be included, if you specify it.

So create your endpoint like this:

```
WebHttpBinding wb = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
wb.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered; // TransferMode.StreamedResponse;
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(myService.IBlah), blah, "");
```

I had this problem when I was streaming an MP3 audio from a WCF WebGet and I couldn't see Content-Length. Once your endpoint is configured with `Buffered` transfer mode, you will start seeing `Content-Length`.

For me this was only half the battle. In order to properly play MP3 on Chrome, I had to also add `Accept-Ranges: bytes` to the response headers so that the audio was seekable on Chrome.