# Why do I get numeric characters in my raw JSON response from WCF?

Tags: json, wcf

Switching from XML to JSON on the fly in a WCF RESTful service.  When I POST some JSON to the service from Fiddler, I get the right JSON back, but if you look in the RAW response, you get the JSON message that is sandwiched in between 2 numbers, like this:
[image]

Is this problematic for parsing the JSON?  Like I said, the actual JSON looks fine.

Comment: Did you try parsing the JSON resposne to see if it caused a problem?

Comment: @Tim not yet; just wondered why the raw response included the numbers.

Comment: @Tim : I get a message that says "response is not valid JSON"

Comment: This is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858145/wcf-disable-chunked-transfer-encoding